# Struggling with calling a method using multiprocessing in my REST API program in Python

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

I'm studying Python, but I have a terrible teacher and I don't know anything about how to deal with the `multiprocessing` module in a REST API program on windows. I have an application which stores data about people (patients of a hospital) and I have to include a method which makes statistics about this data in the background.

```
from flask import Flask
from hospital_controller import hospital_api
from report_generator import statistic_reporting
import multiprocessing

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
   print('Hello')
   REPORT_GENERATOR_PID = multiprocessing.Queue()
   if REPORT_GENERATOR_PID == 0:
       statistic_reporting()
       exit(0)

print(hospital_api)
app.register_blueprint(hospital_api)

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

In this way, the multiprocess call just gets ignored. Everything else is fine, so I'm running the REST API.
I tried to call it in different ways:

```
 p = multiprocessing.Queue(target=statistic_reporting())
```

In this case the `statistic_reporting()` method is running fine but the API server itself doesn't respond.
Summarising, I can't make both of these things to work at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

`multiprocessing.Queue()` does not create a new process and it does not take a *target* argument. You seem somewhat confused and really need to read a good tutorial on multiprocessing. But, for what it's worth, the following code is an example of Flask application that starts a background process. But, I regret that I am not in a position to provide you that complete multiprocessing tutorial that you seem to be needing. So I don't know what value, if any, you will get from this.

```py
from flask import Flask
from multiprocessing import Process

app = Flask(__name__)

def background_task():
    import time

    print('Background task started.')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('Background task ended.')

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    Process(target=background_task).start()
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! The background task starts working if the http route is matches with that given route. You are right i dont know anything about multiprocessing in Python, what is more i slightly know anything about the Python itself. The called class doesnt really do what i want, but i guess that is another problem and the multiprocess part is done.